# Best way to check arguments before running method

Tags: java, arguments, conditional-statements

So,
for example if I had a method called "divide" and it would just divide to ints and return an int, what would be the best way to check that the divisor is != 0

Way 1:

```
    private int divide(int i1, int i2) {
         if(i2 == 0) return 0;

         return i1/i2;
}
```

Way 2:

```
    private int divide(int i1, int i2) {
        if(i2 != 0) {
            return i1/i2;       
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Which one would you prefer?

EDIT: I know, that you'd normally not write such a function, since it would throw an exception if the divisor is 0 anyways. This is just to clearify my question.

EDIT 2: I just changed the method function to return 0, if the divisor is 0.

Comment: I always prefer the one with less parse nodes. The `else` after either a `return` or a `throw` is always redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to throw a `RuntimeException` whenever the second argument is `0`, you do not need to do anything.

```
private int divide(int i1, int i2) {
    return i1/i2; // This will throw an ArithmeticException
}
```

The above code will throw an [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) which extends from `RuntimeException` thereby reducing your work of throwing a `RuntimeException` explicitly.

*Edit:* Since the code snippet in your question was just a sample, here is the updated answer.

It is more cleaner and better to avoid an unnecessary `else` such as in this case, because the `else` is another branch block and if you're really not going to do much in there than just a `return`, the code is better of without it.

If it goes into the `if`, it returns, thereby leaving the `else` useless and if it doesn't, then just the `return` is enough as all you need to do is `return` back from the method.

```
private int divide(int i1, int i2) {
    if(i2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return i1/i2;
}
```

Comment: It was just an example, to clearify what my question is.

Comment: @TimoV - Honestly, you shouldn't use such an example. I suggest you change your question to throw a checked exception rather than an unchecked one because the best solution to your current problem at hand, is what I've posted above.

Comment: @TimoV - I updated the answer after your edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is more common and (I believe more widely accepted) to use the first method, as if you are checking more than one or two variables, you begin to get very long line indentations. The first method is also more concise as compared to the second.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer second one because its readable and if your requirement change in future like if
i2==o then you may maintain it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the second way, because it's more readable like Sanjay Rajjadi said,

```
private int divide(int i1, int i2) {
    if(i2 != 0) {
        return i1/i2;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

but why throwing the exception? u can show an Alert or a message to the user asking him to insert a new int.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer none of them, because throwing a `RuntimeException` is not a good practice; you should create your own subclass of Exception. Besides that, I can't see why it is necessary to explicitly throw this exception, as the resulting exception (`java.lang.ArithmeticException`) is a subclass of `RuntimeException`.
Maybe you should try something like this?

```
private int divide(int i1, int i2) throws DivisionByZeroException {
    try {
        return i1/i2;
    } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new DivisionByZeroException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int divide(int i1, int i2) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(i2==0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument 'divisor' is 0");
    else return i1/i2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None.

You don't have to *explicitly* `throw` that exception, [`java.lang.ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) will be thrown if the divisor is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I really have to, I would use the first method because of the massive amount of indentations one will get if checking many arguements.

Nevertheless I have to say: Always evaluate twice if such a check is needed.

In your particular case, the check is redundant as division by 0 will throw an `ArithmeticException` whichs will say: `/ by zero`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java/271874#271874) for a brilliant explanation why one often exaggerates with checks, especially with null/not null checks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method. You need not to check for zero. Just throw arithmetic exception.

```
private int divide( int i1, int i2 ) throws ArithmeticException
{
    return i1/i2;
}
```